# How enable guest comments in Wordpress 4.7 API

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I use WP-API plugin version 2 and now after update WP API integrated to WP by default, but in new version Wordpress 4.7 by default disabled guest comments via API. How enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved I add this line to WP theme functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );
```